# RegEx fetch a value data by sentence

Tags: regex, node.js

**Hello community,**

I'm trying to figure out how I can get only the value of a specific key. Let's say:

```
Item Number: 121225734541
transaction:: 1205737904002
Price: C $4.73 
Shipping price: Free
```

I need to get only the value after the ":" char.

Key: Item Number, Value: 121225734541

Any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - In fact, yes. But what were *your* ideas? Did you have any? Which ones? In what way did they not work? Show your code. (If you had no ideas and did not try anything, you are in the wrong line of work. If you did try anything and it failed, explain what you have tried.)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/5buspznn/1/

```
var raw_data = 'Item Number: 121225734541\ntransaction: 1205737904002\nPrice: C $4.73\nShipping price: Free'

var data_object = {}

raw_data.split('\n').map(function (data_line) {
    var parsed = data_line.match(/(.*?):(.*)/)
    data_object[parsed[1]] = parsed[2].trim()
})

console.log(data_object)
```

returns this:

```
Object {
    Item Number: "121225734541",
    transaction: "1205737904002",
    Price: "C $4.73",
    Shipping price: "Free"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
([^:]+):\s*([^\n]+)
# anything not :
# followed by : and whitespaces, eventually
# anything not a newline
```

The first capture group holds your `key`, the second your `value`.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wI9iH7/1).